# How to return HTML from Next.js middleware?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I'm trying to return HTTP Status Code 410 (gone) alongside a custom simple HTML:

```
   <h1>Error 410</h1>
   <h2>Permanently deleted or Gone</h2>
   <p>This page is not found and is gone from this server forever</p>
```

Is it possible? Because I can't find a method on [NextResponse](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/server#nextresponse) object.

How can I return HTML from middleware?

Answer (score 5):

This is not supported anymore.

> Middleware can no longer produce a response body as of v12.2+.

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/returning-response-body-in-middleware

Comment: But it still works in Next 13. When would it be removed?

Comment: I would expect it **not** to work in Next 13.

Comment: But it works. I didn't know they have plans to deprecate it. It might be that their docs is not up to date.

Comment: Then how do you currently respond HTML in the middleware?

Comment: I figured it out. I use `new NextResponse`.

Comment: It's supported again as of Next 13

Answer (score 3):

While it's true that returning a response body from middleware has been disabled from version v12.2, Next.js v13 reintroduced the ability to produce a response as an experimental feature through the [`allowMiddlewareResponseBody`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#producing-a-response) flag in `next.config.js`.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        allowMiddlewareResponseBody: true
    }
}
```

After enabling this experimental flag, you can return a response from your middleware as follows.

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {
    return new NextResponse(
        `
            <h1>Error 410</h1>
            <h2>Permanently deleted or Gone</h2>
            <p>This page is not found and is gone from this server forever</p>
        `,
        { status: 410, headers: { 'content-type': 'text/html' } }
    )
}
```

Comment: how do i serve html file directly?

Comment: @ManjunathGk You could technically parse the HTML file as a string, then send the string in `NextResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the type. there is no method to send html

```
type NextApiResponse<T = any> = ServerResponse<IncomingMessage> & {
    send: Send<T>;
    json: Send<T>;
    status: (statusCode: number) => NextApiResponse<T>;
    redirect(url: string): NextApiResponse<T>;
    redirect(status: number, url: string): NextApiResponse<T>;
    setPreviewData: (data: object | string, options?: {
        maxAge?: number;
        path?: string;
    }) => NextApiResponse<T>;
    clearPreviewData: (options?: {
        path?: string;
    }) => NextApiResponse<T>;
    unstable_revalidate: () => void;
    revalidate: (urlPath: string, opts?: {
        unstable_onlyGenerated?: boolean;
    }) => Promise<void>;
}
```

`express` has `sendFile`

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

`NextApiResponse,` send`and`json`

> ```
> res.json(body) - Sends a JSON response. body must be a serializable object
> res.send(body) - Sends the HTTP response. body can be a string, an object or a Buffer
> ```

you can redirect the user to a URL where you display your html

Answer (score 0):

[As of Next 13.1](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#nextjs-advanced-middleware), you can return a response body in middleware, without setting any flags:

> The experimental.allowMiddlewareResponseBody configuration option inside next.config.js is no longer required.

[Producing a response](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response) is still poorly documented. You can return HTML with the `NextReponse` constructor, even though it's not documented:

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = new NextResponse(`<html>...</html>`);

  // There is no content-type by default!
  response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');

  // set response headers, cookies, etc, if desired
  return response;
}
```

The [producing a response](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#producing-a-response) documentation also shows a convenience `.json()` method. However note the docs reference an undefined `Response` variable without explanation. I have not tested this code

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return Response.json(
    { success: false, message: 'authentication failed' },
    { status: 401 }
  )
}
```

Next.js middleware is still fairy immature as you can see from the documentation, and Next.js also has no native way to chain middleware responses(!) so if you have your own middleware chaining, you'll need to manually detect that some middleware is returning HTML.