# Next JS 13 Error page doesn't handle fetch api error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As what I understand based on [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling) of next js with app router, I create a error.tsx page inside my app folder (app/[lang]/error.tsx) -- the file consist the code that are shown in docs. also I have some api calls (fetch) inside a file in this route: src/api/categories/index.ts (because I want these apis call in server (SSG)) but if my api doesn't resolve it shows me default error of next js like below:
[image]

but I don't want this I need to show an error page for that. here is also my error page code:

```js
"use client";

export default function Error({
 error,
 reset,
}: {
 error: Error;
 reset: () => void;
}) {
 console.log(error);
 return (
   <div>
     <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
     <button onClick={() => reset()}>Try again</button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

I also tried to copy this file next to the index.ts (apis file) because as the docs says :

> Next.js will forward the resulting Error object to the nearest
> error.js file as the error prop

but dosn't work. how can I do that?

edit: here is my directory of the project right now:

```
src/
├─ api/
│  ├─ categories/
│  │  ├─ index.ts
├─ app/
│  ├─ [lang]/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
│  │  ├─ layout.tsx
│  │  ├─ global-error.tsx
│  │  ├─ error.tsx
```

Comment: Have you wrapped the parts of your UI you want covered by `error.js` in an error boundary? Did you also see the last couple of paragraphs of that page which look relevant.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know exactly what you mean by that, I also create global-error.tsx inside app/[lang]/global-error.tsx expecting that as what I understand from the docs "Unlike the root error.js, the global-error.js error boundary wraps the entire application, and its fallback component replaces the root layout when active. Because of this, it is important to note that global-error.js must define its own <html> and <body> tags." but still no luck. if you meant something other than this can you explain more simple please? @Andy

Comment: I think the `/api` folder should be inside the `/app` folder. Am I wrong? Did you try it before?

Comment: I did not try that, thanks for the offer I will let you know if it's working or not @Emre

Comment: Still not working, I tried to put api directory inside app directory also inside app/[lang] directory but same result @Emre

Comment: Sorry @EshgheCode. These videos might help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVt-EtR6_eQ & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_vVsPwvcsg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return HTML from Next.js middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570148/how-to-return-html-from-next-js-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the error as a state, the error boundaries only catch errors in the rendering phase:

```js
const [error, setError] = useState("")

if(!res.ok){
  setError("error")
}

if(error){
  throw new Error("Fetch failed!")
}
```